# MUI DataGrid height transition

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, height, transition

```
        const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState<number>(10);

        <DataGrid
          pageSize={pageSize}
          autoHeight
          ...
        />
```

The DataGrid is autoHeight. The default pageSize is set to 10. After invoke the `setPageSize`, the pageSize will changed, and the DataGrid conent and height will change dynamically.

Is there any way to make the transition effect in height in DataGrid after the pageSize value is changed. Thanks.